# How can I hide the title bar in an android application

Tags: java, android, css

I have been trying to find a way to hide the title bar in my android application.
I used *@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen* in the android manifest. It worked but the background gets set to black and all the text views get set to white. Is their a way to have the background set to white and text to black without having to set them all individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple version, try to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. This will keep "light" theme but remove action bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can ovveride the Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen  background color/text colors by applying additional styles. For example if you wanted your background color to be white you would apply the style:

@color/your_background__color